# How to test a file upload in a struts unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, struts2, struts2-junit-plugin

In Struts 2, I can use `request.setParameter()` for testing normal form submissions. But, how can one test uploading a file? Is there an equivalent of `request.setParameter()` which lets you pass a file as the parameter value?

I also have a `setFile()` method on my action which I could use to set the file before I call `actionProxy.execute()`, but, would doing that not reset the value of my file if there's no file on the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is working for me:

```
    File newFile = new File("/path/to/file.png");
    ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/uploadAction");        
    UploadAction action = (UploadAction) proxy.getAction();                

    action.setMyUploadFile( newFile );
    String result = proxy.execute();
```